# in cocoa,Aout serial communiction using nsfilehandle issues 

Tags: cocoa, nsfilehandle

i have a software about serial communication , 
it to be develop in MAC os=10.5.8 using cocoa 's nsfilehandle , 
test ok ,

but when MAC os upgrading to 10.6 ,the program work no normal, can't receive nsfilehandle's notification .

it's why ,

Comment: my meaning :
how to get NSFilehandle notifiction on Mac os 10.6

Comment: Please post some code that relates to the problem. How are you registering for the `NSFileHandle` notifications? Is your app multi-threaded?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that something in your program was relying on undefined behavior, and that behavior changed in 10.6.

Comment: i use the normal SDK (nsfilehandle) ,why ?

Answer (score 0):

i use NSFilehandle to serial communication , dely on the nsfilehandle notification to interact with UI , it run ok On Mac os 10.5.8 ,but upgade to 10.6 , i can't receive any nsfilehandle notification , i using the cocoa normal type ,why have the condition .